# Time Log Monitoring System PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time

I am having problems with my Time Keeper System. Well, in my system you can see the employees time logs(ex. Date, Check-In, Break-Out, Break-In, Check-Out). I used the date as the main source of getting one's records after uploading the csv file from a bio metrics machine. now what bothers me is that it was too late when i just realized that some of the employees has dual-shifts in one(1) working day. for example:

in the date 04/05/13(mm/dd/YY) the employee checked in at 1:00 AM and checked out at 10:00 AM. In the same date at 9:00 PM the employee logged back for his dual-shift so the employee's check-out date and time would be 04/06/13 at 6:00 AM.

the output now in my systems record is just gonna based on date. so in the date 04/06/13, there will be no check-in because it's recorded in the date 04/05/13 and what I did in the system is if there is no check-in it will not also show the rest of the record. so it would be like this:

```
| ACNo |   Date    |   CheckIn   |  Breakout  |   Breakin  | Checkout
|      |           |             |            |            |
| 1220 | 4/05/2013 | 01:00:18 AM | 5:46:58 AM | 6:22:41 AM | 9:42:19 AM
| 1220 | 4/05/2013 | 09:00:00 PM |            |            |
| 1220 | 4/06/2013 |             | 1:00:00 AM | 2:00:00 AM | 6:00:00 AM
this 3rd row will not appear in the system because of the condition that if there will be no
check-in it will not show the rest of the record.
```

the continuation of the table above is the calculation of the employee's Tardiness, Over-Break, Over-Time and Under time (It will be calculated by row). so if there is always a employee that will have dual-shift of work, i cannot see its total records for the day. What i want to do now is to base on the state of Check-In and Check-out. by the way, my database tables are CheckIn, CheckOut, and Breaks.

The CheckIn:

```
| CIn_ACNo |   CIn_Date  |   CIn_Time   | 
|          |             |              | 
|   1220   |  4/05/2013  | 01:00:18 AM  |  
|   1220   |  4/05/2013  | 09:00:00 PM  |
```

CheckOut:

```
| COut_ACNo |  COut_Date  |   COut_Time  | 
|           |             |              |  
|   1220    |  4/05/2013  |  09:42:19 AM |
|   1220    |  4/06/2013  |  06:00:00 AM |
```

and here is the code i used to get the results:

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("Select * from checkin where CIn_ACNo = '$id' order by CIn_Date asc");
$stop1 = mysql_num_rows($sql1);
if(!$stop1){
$checkin = null;
}
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)) {
$date1 = $row1['CIn_Date'];
$checkin = $row1['CIn_Time'];


//temporary change schedule
$tempsched = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tempschedchange where TempACNo = '$ID' AND TempDate =   '$date1'");
$stop9 = mysql_num_rows($tempsched);
if(!$stop9){
    $tempin = null; $tempout = null; $tempdate = null;
}
while($row9 = mysql_fetch_array($tempsched)){
    $tempname = $row9['TempName'];
    $tempacno = $row9['TempACNo'];
    $tempdate = $row9['TempDate'];
    $tempin = $row9['TempSchedIn'];
    $tempout = $row9['TempSchedOut'];
}

//break out count
$sql2 = mysql_query("Select * from breaks where break_date = '$date1' AND break_ex = 'Out' AND break_acno = '$id' order by break_date asc");
$stop2 = mysql_num_rows($sql2);
    if(!$stop2){
        $breakoutt = "-";
    }
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
        $breakoutt = $stop2;
        $breakout = $row2['break_time'];
    }
//break in count
$sql3 = mysql_query("Select * from breaks where break_date = '$date1' AND break_ex = 'Out Back' AND break_acno = '$id' order by break_date asc");
$stop3 = mysql_num_rows($sql3);
    if(!$stop3){
        $breakinn = "-";
        $OBB="-";
    }
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql3)) {
    $breakinn = $stop3 + $stop2;
    $breakin = $row3['break_time'];

        if($breakinn > 2) {
            if($breakinn % 2){
                $breakinnn = $breakinn - 1;
                $breakinn = $breakinnn / 2;
            }else{
                $breakinn = $breakinn / 2;
            }
        }
        elseif($breakinn <= 2) {
            $breakinn = 1;
        }
}

//checkout
$sql4 = mysql_query("Select * from checkout where COut_Date = '$date1' AND COut_ACNo = '$id'");
$stop4 = mysql_num_rows($sql4);
    if(!$stop4){
        $checkout = "-";
    }
while($row4 = mysql_fetch_array($sql4)) {
    $date4 = $row4['COut_Date'];
    $checkout = $row4['COut_Time'];
}

//BREAKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!important
//break out 1
$sql5 = mysql_query("Select * from breaks where break_date = '$date1' AND break_acno = '$id' AND break_ex = 'Out' order by break_date desc limit 1");
$stop5 = mysql_num_rows($sql5);
    if(!$stop5) {
        $breakout1 = 0;
    }
    while($row5 = mysql_fetch_array($sql5)) {
        $breakout1 = $row5['break_time'];
        if($breakout == $breakout1){
        $breakout1 = 0;
        }
    }
//break in 1
$sql6 = mysql_query("Select * from breaks where break_date = '$date1' AND break_acno = '$id' AND break_ex = 'Out Back' order by break_date desc limit 1");
$stop6 = mysql_num_rows($sql6);
    if(!$stop6) {
        $breakin1 = 0;
    }
while($row6 = mysql_fetch_array($sql6)) {
    $date6 = $row6['break_date'];
    $breakin1 = $row6['break_time'];
    if($breakin == $breakin1){
        $breakin1 = 0;
        }
}
//break out 2
$sql7 = mysql_query("Select * from breaks where break_date = '$date1' AND break_acno = '$id' AND break_ex = 'Out' order by break_date desc limit 2");
$stop7 = mysql_num_rows($sql7);
    if(!$stop7) {
        $breakout2 = 0;
    }
    while($row7 = mysql_fetch_array($sql7)) {
        $breakout2 = $row7['break_time'];
        if($breakout1 == $breakout2){
        $breakout2 = 0;
        }
    }
//break in 2
$sql8 = mysql_query("Select * from breaks where break_date = '$date1' AND break_acno = '$id' AND break_ex = 'Out Back' order by break_date desc limit 2");
$stop8 = mysql_num_rows($sql8);
    if(!$stop8) {
        $breakin2 = 0;
    }
while($row8 = mysql_fetch_array($sql8)) {
    $date6 = $row8['break_date'];
    $breakin2 = $row8['break_time'];
    if($breakin1 == $breakin2){
        $breakin2 = 0;
    }
}
```

i need some help on how to create a condition that will get the values of checkin and checkout without referring to the date only. instead it will base on the Check In and Check Out of the employee. Like, when there is a one record of checkin it will automatically pair to a checkout. Im not this good in making conditions in MySQL like using JOINS and what so ever just simple Queries as you can notice in my codes. so please, got any idea how to do this? please help me out guys! thank you very much for reading this very long explanation. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Making a few assumptions (that you fields are just varchar), the following will get you the start and end time of shifts. You can use this as a sub select and join it against the breaks to get the results you want.

```
SELECT a.ACNo, STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(a.Date, ' ', a.Time), '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p') AS StartTime, MIN(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(b.Date, ' ', b.Time), '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p')) AS EndTime
FROM CheckIn a
INNER JOIN CheckOut b
ON a.ACNo = b.ACNo
AND STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(b.Date, ' ', b.Time), '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p') > STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(a.Date, ' ', a.Time), '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p')
GROUP BY a.ACNo, STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(a.Date, ' ', a.Time), '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p')
```

Not sure on the format of your breaks table to go further with this.

By the way, it would likely be FAR easier to do if rather than storing a separate date and time you just put that into a datetime field.

EDIT - Explanation of the query.

It joins the table of CheckIns against the table of CheckOuts based on the ACNo and also the Checkout date and time being greater than the CheckIn date and time. This potentially results in hundreds of intermediate rows, as the CheckIn for the (say) 1st of Jan for Fred will be joined against every CheckOut for Fred for every day after that. The query uses the MIN aggregate function, grouping by the ACNo and the CheckIn date and time to reduce the number of rows to just the CheckIn date / times and the first CheckOut after it.

A large part of what makes this (otherwise relatively simple) query complicated to look at is merging the dates and times together (and I have assumed that they are just text fields - if they are date type field and a time type field then this might explain why it is giving you issues).

Can you amend the design of your database? If you can then storing the dates and times in a combined datetime field (or as a unix timestamp) would make this easier to understand (and a lot faster).

If they were date/time fields then the following (simpler looking) query would give you the basics:-

```
SELECT a.ACNo, a.Date_Time AS StartTime, 
MIN(b.Date_Time) AS EndTime
FROM CheckIn a
INNER JOIN CheckOut b
ON a.ACNo = b.ACNo
AND b.Date_Time > a.Date_Time
GROUP BY a.ACNo, a.Date_Time
```